# Typescript shows error during mocking axios in Vitest

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, ts-jest, vitest

I want to mock to mock axios get request in Vitest. During mocking the request using `mockimplementationOnce()`, the typescript error appears. It says, the following:
`Property 'mockImplementationOnce' does not exist on type '<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T, any>, D = any>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<D> | undefined) => Promise<R>'.ts(2339)`

For solving the above problem , i defined `mockAxios` as follows:

```
import { vi, expect, it } from "vitest";
import axios from "axios";

vi.mock("axios");

const mockAxios = axios as vi.Mocked<typeof axios>

it("Should return valid value", async () => {

  mockAxios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
      data: { completed: false, title: "dummy data for mocking", userId: 1 },
    })
  );
  ...
  });
});
```

Also, the **mocks** folder includes:

```
import { vi } from "vitest";

export default {
  get: vi.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
      data: { completed: false, title: "dummy data for mocking", userId: 1 },
    })
  ),
};
```

But again, the following error appears:
`Cannot find namespace 'vi'. Did you mean 'Vi'?ts(2833)`

How can handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are mocking axios using the `__mocks__` folder, that folder would need to be at the root of your project (`__mocks__/axios.ts`, for example). Then all you need to do in your test is the `vi.mock("axios")` line:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { expect, it, vi } from "vitest";

vi.mock("axios");

it("Should return valid value", async () => {
  console.log(axios);
});
```

If you need to customize the mocked function for a particular test, you could use the [`vi.mocked()`](https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-mocked) function. It's really just a type helper that returns the input object, but it types it for you.

```
it("Should return valid value", async () => {
  vi.mocked(axios, true).get.mockResolvedValueOnce({
    data: { completed: true, title: "dummy data for mocking", userId: 1 },
  });

  console.log(await axios.get(""));
  console.log(await axios.get(""));
});
```

The first log would have `completed: true`, the second one would have `false` from the version from `__mocks__`.

Notice the second argument on `vi.mocked<T>(obj: T, deep?: boolean)` is `true`. That is to indicate that it should type the return value with its properties also being mocked.

It is important to note that this function does **not** do any mocking, it just returns the input value but typed as though it has been mocked so you can call things like `.mockReturnedValueOnce()` on it; you still have to call `vi.mock("axios")` at the root of the test file for the mock to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Mocked is in the same namespace as vi, so import directly Mocked instead.

```
import { describe, it, expect, beforeEach, vi, Mocked } from "vitest";
```